# SAS group by first digits

Tags: sas

I have a variable in SAS with a lot of numbers, for example 11000, 30129, 11111, 30999. I want to group this by the first two digits so "11000 and 11111" and "30129 and 30999" will be in a own table.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple,

You have to create a second column and extract the 2 first digit.

Then sort the dataset by this second columns.

```
data test;
 infile datalines dsd ;
   input a : 15. ;
   datalines;
11000,
30129,
11111,
309999,
; 
run;

data test_a;
length val_a $2;
set test;
val_a= SUBSTRN(a,1,2);
run;

proc sort data=test_a out=test_b;
by val_a;
run;
```

Result will be :

```
val_a     a
11        11000
11        11111
30        30129
30        309999
```

And then you can create 2 dataset with selection on the val_a like this :

```
data want data_11 data_30;
set test_b;
if val_a = 11 then output data_11;
if val_a = 30 then output data_30;
run;
```

Regards,

Comment: I edited Tom's answer - val_a needs to be defined as charater variable (see length statement)

Comment: Thanks Vasja for your comment. Strange thing, format val_a 15.; is working perfectly.  I don't see why val_a need to be character. By the way my answer solution the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I did like you, but my new column only shows with ".". But  I think your answer can give me some help anyways, thank you!

```html
data books;

infile "&path\Boken.csv" dlm=';' missover dsd firstobs=2;

 input   ISBN: $12.
   Book: $quote150.;


run;

data test_a;
format val_ISBN 15.;
set books;
val_ISBN= SUBSTRN(ISBN,1,2);
run;

proc sort data=test_a out=test_b;
by val_ISBN;
run;


proc print data=test_b (obs=10) noobs ;
run;
```

Comment: Don't forget the way to say Thank you on stackoverflow :)  (tick my answer as correct) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work